# Using notifyItemRangeChanged/Inserted/Removed when adding values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If I have 10 items in my RecyclerView:

```
Indexes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

And I remove the one at index 2, and insert 2 items in its place, like so:

```
data.remove(2);
data.add(2, object);
data.add(3, object);
```

What methods would I call out of `notifyItemRangeChanged`/`notifyItemRangeInserted`/`notifyItemRangeRemoved`, and what values would I put in them?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, these calls need to be made :

- 1st : notifyItemRemoved(2)
- 2nd : notifyItemInserted(2,2)

a single call to notifyItemInserted() wont do because : (from the docs)

> The items previously located at positionStart and beyond can now be found starting at position positionStart + itemCount.

which is not what is required.

Comment: What values would I use? I'm asking because I don't know if it's inclusive, i.e. if it counts the first index, and how it counts from there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on value you are adding an on item view type...
If the method `getItemViewType()` returns the same value you can call `notifyItemChanged(2); notifyItemInserted(3)`
If not you should do the same as operations on data : `notufyItemRemoved(2); notifyItemRangeInserted(2,2);`
As far as I know it is not needed to put any data (payload)